# Maximum and minimum of a function.

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math

Given a function $f(x) = C(x, 2) + C(N-x,2)$, where N is a constant and C(N, K) is the binomial coefficient choose K from N, we need to find minimum and maximum value. Also, $x > 0$.

So, f(x) = $\frac{N(N-1)}{2} + x(x - N)$
Maximum value is when $x=1$ or $x = N - 1$, since f(x) = f(N-x) but $x > 0$ and minimum value is when $x = N / 2$.

The problem is how to compute minimum and maximum for a larger version of this problem.
$f(x_1,x_2,...,x_k) = C(x_1, 2) + C(x_2, 2) + .... + C(x_k, 2)$, where $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_k = N$ and $x_1,x_2,...,x_k > 0$.

I need some idea on how to use the 2d version to expand to $k$ dimension and find minimum and maximum value. Let, $C(1, 2) = 0$.

Comment: you will need the Lagrange-Multiplier function

Comment: Is there some intuitive idea that can be used to expand the 2d answer?

Comment: Is it not a tooooo general title ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: you can use $AM-GM$ inequality $$\sqrt{x(N-x)}\le \frac{x+N-x}{2}=\frac{N}{2}$$

Comment: Can you tell me what I need to progress through my current state on the problem? And maybe I can use your hint.

Comment: i think you can use my hint

Comment: A little hard to digest your hint. Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

Using lagrange multiplier function.

For maximum,

$$f(X)=x_1(x_1-1)/2+x_2(x_2-1)/2+....+x_k(x_k-1)/2$$
$$=>f(X)=\frac{x_1^2+..+x_k^2}{2}-\frac{N}{2}$$

$$c(X) => x_1+x_2+..+x_k = N(constraint)$$

new function

g(X) = f(X) + p*c(X)

derivative of g(X) with respect to x
$$=>x_1-p=0$$
$$=>x_1=p$$

Similarly,

$$=>x_2=p,..,x_k=p$$

Putting them into the constraints,

$$p+p+..+p=N$$
$$=>pk=N$$
$$=>p=N/k$$

So $x_1=x_2=..=x_k=N/k$

So putting the values 
$$f_{max} = \frac{k\frac{N^2}{k^2}-N}{2}$$
$$=>f_{max} = \frac{N^2-kN}{2k}$$
$$=>f_{max} = \frac{N(N-k)}{2k}$$

$x_k >= 1$ can be enforced by first distributing 1 to each $x_i$ and solving for N-k using above method or by adding extra constraint(look at reference)

for minimum, maximize f'(X) = -f(X)

$$=>f(X)=\frac{N}{2}-\frac{x_1^2+..+x_k^2}{2}$$

$$c(X) => x_1+x_2+..+x_k = N$$

new objective function,

$$g(X) = f(X) + p*c(X) + q(X>=1)$$

convert X>=1 to -x<=-1

$$=>g(X) = f(X) + p*c(X) + q(-1+X)$$

derivative of new function wrt to $x_1$

$$-x_1-p+q=0$$
$$-x_1-p+q=0$$
$$x_1=q-p$$

Either q = 0 or -X + 1 = 0,
if $q=0$ $x_1 = -p$ but $p>=0$ so $x_1 <= 0$ which is invalid 
so $x_1=1$ and similarly all x'es = 1.

References:
[Lagrangian multiplier with equality and inequality constraints](http://mat.gsia.cmu.edu/classes/QUANT/NOTES/chap4/node6.html)